# Proof of the G-Parity Relation $G=(-1)^IC$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, isospin-symmetry

As stated in the question title, I am trying to prove the relation (pg. 144 of Griffiths' Introduction to Elementary Particle' or pg. 126 on Riazuddin's 'High Energy Physics') concerning the eigenvalues of a multiplet of isospin $I$ and charge conjugation number $C$:
$$G=(-1)^IC,$$
**My problem:**
I am guided to do it by proving first, an here is where I have my problem, that $$e^{-i\pi \hat{I_2} }|I,0\rangle=(-1)^I|I,0\rangle,$$
where $\hat{I_2}$ stands for the component $2$ of the isospin operator.

**My attempt:**
I have attempted the proof by expanding the exponential factor in the series, by using $\hat I_2=\sigma_y$ without any success. I have also checked the original Yang, Lee paper where they describe the 4-matrix representation of $\hat I_2$:
$$\hat{I_2}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -i&0 &0\\i&0&0&0\\0&0&0&-i\\0&0&i&0
\end{bmatrix},$$
but again achieving nothing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will desist from doing your homework problem for you, so I won't do your isospin rotation as your text presumably wishes you to do it, by analogy to angular momentum rotation matrices $d^I_{00}(\pi)=\langle I,0 | \exp (i \pi I_2)|I,0\rangle$ . I'll just get the point across in a geometric way,  as evoked by your text.

Observe that, for an isosinglet, your isorotation will have no effect, $I_2 |I(=0),0\rangle=0$; while for an isotriplet, *I*=1, just about the only case you'll encounter, you know from the [Rodrigues' rotation formula for vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula#Matrix_notation) that, for an antisymmetric generator of a rotation around unit axis ***k***, 
$$
\mathbf{K}= \left (\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -k_z & k_y \\
k_z & 0 & -k_x \\
-k_y & k_x & 0
\end{array}\right )~;
$$
so that the orthogonal finite rotation matrix is just
$$
 \mathbf{R} (\theta)=e^{\theta \mathbf{K}} = 1\!\!1 + (\sin\theta) \mathbf{K} + (1-\cos\theta)\mathbf{K}^2  ~. 
$$
(Note your isospin generators are hermitean, not antisymmetric, so $K_2\mapsto iI_2$. You may find them in conventional isotriplet notation in [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_group_SO(3)#A_note_on_Lie_algebra) and, since they are strictly *equivalent*, they would yield the same conclusion, with the neutral pion now in the middle of the triplet.).

Thus for $R_2$, an isorotation around the 2/y axis by *π*, a parity reflection in isospace flipping the charges of the charged pions, ($k_y=1$, $k_x=k_z=0$), the above formula collapses to 
$$
R_2=1\!\!1+2\mathbf{K}^2= \mathrm {diag} (-1,1,-1). 
$$

Recall that the eigenstate of $K_z$ with eigenvalue 0 in this specific representation is (0,0,1), hence its eigenvalue w.r.t. the action of $R_2$ so found is -1.

---

$R_2$ actually is the conjugacy operation on *SU(2)*, so, combined with *C*, yields *G* commuting with isospin, as observed by [Charlie Goebel in 1956](http://cosmology.princeton.edu/~mcdonald/examples/EP/goebel_pr_103_258_56.pdf).

It is actually not that hard to prove that for the isoquintet, *I*=2, [Curtright, Fairlie, Zachos (2014)](https://www.academia.edu/10251056/A_Compact_Formula_for_Rotations_as_Spin_Matrix_Polynomials), the eigenvalue is +1, as per the generic formula.

A note on your attempt: it could be pursued, but with blood, sweat, and tears. What you have is the 1/2 x 1/2 reducible quartet rep, in *bad* normalization. You may also work out the antidiagonal 4x4 *C*, take it out of their *G*, confirm it is R(2) proportional to their I(2), by coincidence, and reduce the rep into a triplet and a singlet, and Clebsch to observe the opposite signs for the $\pi^0$ versus the $\eta$. You might be able to climb the Eiger in slippers, but do you really want to?

Comment: Thanks for the edit and for the complete answer. My attempt was the only way I could think of solving it, so I don't really have any special crush in it, so, I prefer to climb the Eiger in an easier way. Clarified that,  I'm working on your proposed way to solve it at the moment!

Comment: yes, given the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_D-matrix#Wigner_.28small.29_d-matrix), it amounts to a trivial symmetry of the Legendre polynomials.